# What apps in base Android can be replaced?

Tags: applications

I've seen that you can replace the default launcher app with something like LauncherPro, the onscreen keyboard with Swype or ShapeWriter, and I've heard of others. Does anyone have a list of all default apps in the base Android OS (version 2.2 preferred) that can be replaced?

Comment: Strictly speaking, neither of those examples are part of the Operating System.

Comment: That is correct - updated question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Keyboard can be replaced
- Browser can be replaced (Opera, xScope (i like), Dolphin HD, etc.)
- Launcher can be replaced
- Gallery can be replaced (3d gallery is my favorite)
- Camera can be replaced (Camera 360 (drains battery like crazy), Retro Camera, etc.)
- Hell you can even replace the kernel if you root.
- Not an app, but you can add search providers like getting the DuckDuckGo app which allows you to search using all search tools, but ddg vs google.

Comment: Also, phone, contacts and sms apps can be replaced.